# Stuck on setuping Jekyll project for static sites

Tags: github, terminal, rubygems, jekyll

I'm following the [Jekyll Quick-start guide here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/).

The second step doesn't work

```
~ $ gem install jekyll
~ $ jekyll new myblog
~ $ cd myblog
~/myblog $ jekyll serve
# => Now browse to http://localhost:4000
```

[image]

Command not found? I just installed Jekyll. I want to create my first static blog using GitHub pages, I have the page already set up: https://github.com/leongaban/leongaban.github.io and it currently redirects to my old host.

Is there a step I'm missing in setting up Jekyll?

```
- GEM PATHS:
 - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
 - /Users/leongaban/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
```

---

This is the contents of my bash_profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/share/python:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib"
alias sublime="/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
alias edit="/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
alias solr='cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whoat/solr/whoat/;pwd'
export PATH="/Users/leongaban/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin"

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

"~/.bash_profile" 10L, 502C
```

Comment: Is your gem directory in your path?

Comment: Oh no it's in this directory `/Users/leongaban/.gem/ruby/2.0.0` Do I need to cd there and install it there?

Comment: `/Users/leongaban/.gem/ruby/2.0.0` will need to be in your path for this to work.

Comment: My path for my project? So setup my Github page/Jekyll blog there?

Comment: The path to `/Users/leongaban/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin` will need to be in your computer's $PATH to access jekyll

Comment: Ok just added this to my bash_profile `export PATH="/Users/leongaban/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin"` trying again, fail :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44455/discussion-between-leon-gaban-and-cdub)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your path on your machine isn't aware of where the `jekyll` binary is...

Update your `$PATH` to:

`export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/leongaban/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bin:$PATH"`

You may need to reinstall `jekyll` for this to work.